# Splitting data field into two columns & Inserting it to an existing table (MYSQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, database

im trying to split a specific column in an already existing table in MYSQL into two columns, AND grab the returning two columns and inserting them into an already existing table.

I just started learning MYSQL couple of days ago, sorry if thats a noob questions:

here is what i tried so far:

MYSQL Code begins :

```
SELECT substring_index(substring_index(ZIP_code, '-',1), '-', -1) as ZIP,
       substring_index(substring_index(ZIP_code, '-',2), '-', -1) as Extended_info,
from Region.Address
```

MYSQL Code Ends :

this did split my datafield which looks like this '12345-990001' into two columns, one as the ZIP and the second as additional data. the problem is that i cant add the return of this into another table that i have. here is the syntax that im using now (its not working though):

MYSQL Code begins :

```
INSERT INTO TABLE Location 
(SELECT substring_index(substring_index(ZIP_code, '-',1), '-', -1) as ZIP,
       substring_index(substring_index(ZIP_code, '-',2), '-', -1) as Extended_info,
from Region.Address) where ZIP is varchar(64), AND Extended_info is varchar(64)
```

MYSQL Code Ends :

any help that would be much appreciated, thank you in advance!

Comment: Removed sql-server tag because the code is explicitly MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should *always* use a column list with `insert`.  The problem is that your query is being interpreted as:

```
insert into location(select . . .)
```

And `select` is not a valid column.  Also, the word `table` is not necessary.  So try this:

```
INSERT INTO Location(zip, extended_info) 
    SELECT substring_index(substring_index(ZIP_code, '-',1), '-', -1) as ZIP,
           substring_index(substring_index(ZIP_code, '-',2), '-', -1) as Extended_info,
    from Region.Address;
```

Note:  I am guessing what the column names are.

EDIT:

You need to insert a value into all columns that have no default values and cannot accept NULLs.  I would guess that `zip_code` is the field you want to populate with `zip`:

```
INSERT INTO Location(zip_code, extended_info) 
    SELECT substring_index(substring_index(ZIP_code, '-',1), '-', -1) as ZIP,
           substring_index(substring_index(ZIP_code, '-',2), '-', -1) as Extended_info,
    from Region.Address;
```

Perhaps you want something like this:

```
INSERT INTO Location(zip_code, zip, extended_info) 
    SELECT '' as zip_code,
           substring_index(substring_index(ZIP_code, '-',1), '-', -1) as ZIP,
           substring_index(substring_index(ZIP_code, '-',2), '-', -1) as Extended_info,
    from Region.Address;
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon! this got me very close,  with the exception, i keep getting Error Code : 1364 field ZIP_code doesnt have a default value.  but when i do show columns from region.address, its showing as Varchar(64) and No under Null and PRI.  under defaul it says Null.  any idea?